# Is there anything special to the CV format for PhD applicants in Germany?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, cv, germany

I want to pursue my PhD program in Germany. Is there any special format for academic CV to for applying there?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no special format for an academic CV in Germany. In general, CVs in Germany differ somewhat of Angloamerican CVs (see for example this [newspaper article by The Local](http://www.thelocal.de/20130131/47649)). It might be the case, that German professors and selection committees expect a more German CV. However, that should not be a boundary, as academia in Germany is internationally oriented. The Career Center of the RWTH Aachen offers an  [English information sheet about German CVs](http://www.rwth-aachen.de/global/show_document.asp?id=aaaaaaaaaadcphi) that might be helpful. In addition, you could use the [European CV](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/home) from the  European Centre for the Development of Vocational Training as an orientation.

Comment: The format listed at the RWTH link is only appropriate for students before they get to the PhD; it's a resumé, not a CV. The two formats are different.

Comment: @aeismail That's right. At Post-doc level you would typically find the same CV style in Germany like in the US. The OP asked about a CV for a PhD admission.

Comment: The linked *The Local* article says "leave out any description of personal qualities, interests and hobbies". That seems to be oddly in contrast to [the comments on this workplace.se question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31836/mentioning-family-on-cv), where it was companies in Anglo-Saxon countries that were described as not being interested in any not directly job-related qualities, while such personal qualities and the like were rather the norm to be included in various other European countries such as Germany.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper More precisely, Gerhard Winkler advises in _The Local_ to cut the "personal" stuff. He freelances as a consultant for job applicants and generally favours clear and simple resumés. Thus, there are surely others in Germany who would advise to add such a section about personal qualities and interests, especially for young job applicants. In my experience, however, Winkler's advice is better suited for the academic labour market in Germany. Of course, selection committees are interested in voluntary work and experiences **related to the field of research**.